# 遅い socket.io クライアントをシミュレートしたい

Tags: websocket, socket.io

今開発している socket.io サーバーのパフォーマンス検証を行うにあたって、 Slow Client がいた場合の検証を行いたくなりました。

## 質問

- socket.io のクライアントで、その通信速度が遅いようなものを、手元で実現するためのツールなどはありますでしょうか？

  - socket.io でなくても、例えば純粋 websocket に限れば、これを実現する方法などはありますか？

Comment: この辺のサイトが何か参考になるかもしれません。[NetworkSimulationTools](http://networksimulationtools.com/), [Handy TCP/IP Server/Client Tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iptools/), [TCP/IP Builder 1.9](http://www.drk.com.ar/builder.php), [NETWORK SIMULATOR 3.1.15](http://www.sopireminfo.com/indexEn.html), [How to Simulate a TCP/UDP Client Using Netcat](https://ubidots.com/blog/how-to-simulate-a-tcpudp-client-using-netcat/)

Comment: socket.ioで通信層にWebSocketを使わない場合はChromeのDevToolsのNetwork throttlingやFirefoxの開発ツールの帯域制限がつかえます。素のWebSocketやsocket.ioでWebSocketを使う場合は、どちらのブラウザも帯域制限に対応してないようです。